how to get flat output using JMESPath query
I am looking to get flat output like this using jmespath query. filter all SniEnabled
the flat output like csv

FirstWebApp exmple11.com SniEnabled
SecondWebApp xyz.com SniEnabled
SecondWebApp xyz2.com SniEnabled

[
    {
        "hostNameSslStates": [
            {
                "name": "exmple11.com",
                "sslState": "SniEnabled"
            },
            {
                "name": "example22.com",
                "sslState": "Disabled"
            },
            {
                "name": "example23",
                "sslState": "Disabled"
            }
        ],
        "name": "FirstWebApp"
    },
    {
        "hostNameSslStates": [
            {
                "name": "xyz.com",
                "sslState": "SniEnabled"
            },
            {
                "name": "xyz2.com",
                "sslState": "SniEnabled"
            },
            {
                "name": "zyx23.com",
                "sslState": "Disabled"
            }
        ],
        "name": "SecondWebApp"
    }
]


You'll have to pass two queries, I think.
'[].name'

gives
  - FirstWebApp
  - SecondWebApp

and
'[].*[?sslState == `SniEnabled`].name | []'

gives
  - [exmple11.com]
  - [xyz.com, xyz2.com]

Then zip the lists
  - - FirstWebApp
    - [exmple11.com]
  - - SecondWebApp
    - [xyz.com, xyz2.com



Optionally, you can get this list in a single query
'[].[name, [*[?sslState == `SniEnabled`].name]|[]|[]|[] ]'



Create the products and iterate the list (declare a comprehension)
FirstWebApp exmple11.com
SecondWebApp xyz.com
SecondWebApp xyz2.com

